# What are the Consequences of a Miss?

Tags: dungeon-world

So in Dungeon World, the basic mechanic seems to be that you roll 2D6 + Modifier.  If you get a 10+, its a 'good' result, and if you get a 7-9, it's an 'OK' result, with <=6 being 'bad/useless'.  However, I don't see that there are enough consequences for bad/useless!

Let's take as an example **Hack And Slash**.  The move works thusly:

> When  you  attack  an  enemy  in  melee,   roll+STR.   On  a  10+  you
>   deal  your  damage  to  the  enemy  and avoid  their  attack.   At 
>   your  option,   you  may  choose  to  do  +1d6  damage  but  expose 
>   yourself  to  the enemy's  attack.   On  a  7–9,   you  deal  your 
>   damage  to  the  enemy  and  the  enemy makes  an  attack  against
>   you.

So 10+ deals damage.  7-9 deals damage but suffers an incoming attack.  <7?  No effect.  So oddly, it seems you suffer less damage with a complete miss than you do with a hit of some sort.  On top of that, rolling <7 gets you free XP!  What is the downside to players deliberately spamming moves that they know will not land in order to 'farm' XP?

Comment: I think a few things stop players from "farming xp." One, it's boring and possibly difficult to explain in the fiction. Two, your GM moves can get harder and harder until they stop. I mean "on a 1-6 you die" is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> *Introduction*
>
> A miss means that the character's action is unsuccessful or carries major consequences. Unless the move tells you what to do, all moves work the same on a miss—the GM takes action, doing something dangerous to the characters.
>
> *Chapter 12: The GM*
>
> You also make a move when the players give you a golden opportunity. A golden opportunity is any time they ignore a threat or when they fail a roll (6-).
>
> When they give you a golden opportunity, you can make your move just as hard as you like. A hard move is one that is irrevocable and immediate. The players immediately feel the consequences of the move and have to deal with them. Dealing damage is a hard move, since the damage is immediately applied.

On a miss, the GM makes a move. In particular, the GM is empowered to make a hard move, which includes just dealing damage!  Of course, the response should be guided by the GM's principles, including **make a move that follows** (in the fiction). If you miss Hack and Slashing an orc, then it would follow for you to get hit by the orc.  It wouldn't necessarily follow that a cave-in occurs, unless there's been some buildup in the fiction that a cave-in is about to occur.

Comment: Apocalypse World (which Dungeon World is based off of) has a great explanation for when players miss: _All the moves list what should happen on a hit, 7–9 or 10+, so follow them. A few of them list what happens on a miss, so follow those too. For the rest, for now, tell the players this: “on a miss, I’ll tell you what happens.” If you want, just so nobody has any incorrect expectations, you can add this: “...and I promise you won’t like it.”_